# Which find gives better performance in Rails, Child.find(child_id) or parent.children.find(child_id)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have 2 models. For the purpose of this Q&A I call them Parent and Child.

```
# Parent.rb
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children, dependent: :destroy
  # ...
end

# Child.rb
class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
  # ...
end
```

Children resources are nested within the parents resources in the routes file and therefore parent_id will be available in children path.

```
# routes.rb
resources :parents do
  resources :children
end
```

In certain actions of children controller such as update and destroy, there's a need to find the corresponding review record by its ID.

From performance standpoint, will it make a material difference between the following 2 sets of statements?

```
# children_controller.rb
@parent = Parent.find(params[:parent_id])
@child  = Child.find(params[:id])    
# or
@parent = Parent.find(params[:parent_id])
@child  = @parent.children.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Speculation: If `@parent.children` has been called previously, then `@parent.children.find(params[:id])` might be faster than `Child.find(params[:id])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are calling the same method.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find

Asymptotically, the performance difference is nearly negligible. They are both O(1) in time complexity because you have the primary key, unlike using an indexed column (which would be O(log n)).

If you are really looking to see the tiny bit of differences, `@child  = Child.find(params[:id])` is faster because there is less code to run. But at the end of the day, it does not matter.

Comment: When I simulated the code in the console, I noticed the SQL statements generated were as follows: `SELECT  "children".* FROM "chidlren" WHERE "children"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]` and `SELECT  "children".* FROM "children" WHERE "children"."parent_id" = ? AND "children"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["parent_id", 1], ["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]`. Since parent_id is a foreign key in children table, is it appropriate to conclude that the former statement which uses only primary key should be faster and recommended to use, or still doesn't matter?

Comment: the later part of the query `AND "children"."id" = ?`, when it's run, sql db should optimize it and use the primary key to look for the record. Further more, I tested in a table with 82m records, and the performance is almost the same with very small variance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have all the proper indices in place and all that, the only real difference is that there is one more query condition (and hopefully index lookup) if you use the second form `@parent.children.find(id)`.

I always use this form if there's a nested path to ensure that the path is valid.  I recommend you do the same.

Comment: When I simulated the code in the console, I noticed the SQL statements generated were as follows: `SELECT "children".* FROM "children" WHERE "children"."id" = ? LIMIT ? [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]` and `SELECT "children".* FROM "children" WHERE "children"."parent_id" = ? AND "children"."id" = ? LIMIT ? [["parent_id", 1], ["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]`. Since parent_id is a foreign key in children table, is it appropriate to conclude that the former statement which uses only primary key should be faster and therefore recommended to use, or you still recommend the latter?

Comment: As I said, the second query has one more condition.  If your table has proper indices on both columns, the difference in time will be negligible.  There is an added benefit in that it will ensure that the path given is valid (that is to say the parent really is a parent of that child).  So, yes, I recommend the latter.